What does も do in Xも甚だしい?
The i-adjective 甚だしい is very commonly used in the following way:
・「友人として食事に行っただけなのに不倫しているといわれるなんて誤解も甚だしい。」
・「新入社員の彼女の態度は非常識も甚だしい。」
・「彼は会社の携帯電話を使って私用の電話をしているようであるが、公私混同も甚だしい。」
It seems to follow a noun or na-adjective and then も. Is も here to "soften" the phrase as in this question?
That seems counterintuitive considering 非常識も甚だしい to me would be something like "incredibly absurd".
